# Bubble Chart по цвету и размеру

Tags: python, pandas, графика, numpy, matplotlib

Помоги пожалуйста создать Bubble Chart, примерно как на картинке:

[image: картинке]

Их необходимо разместить по цвету и размеру согласно значениям [данных](https://yadi.sk/i/uI9IjSW-au1ARw).

[image: Квантили]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

с разбивкой цветов на 7 квантилей:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_excel(r"D:\download\10лет.xlsx")

figsize = (18,6)
x = df["Population size (millions)"]
y = df["Epedemic intensity, V"]
sz = df["Population size (millions)"].mul(200).astype(int)

bins = [0, .073, .109, .161, .185, .234, .296, 1000]
labels = ["purple", "indigo", "green", "yellow", "gold", "orange", "red"]
col = pd.cut(y, bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)

ax = df.plot.scatter(
    "Population size (millions)", "Epedemic intensity, V",
    c=col, s=sz, alpha=0.75, edgecolors="darkgrey",
    figsize=figsize)
plt.xscale("log")
plt.subplots_adjust()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

можно попытаться использовать "log scale" для оси `X`, чтобы сгладить выбросы:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_excel(r"D:\download\10лет.xlsx")

figsize = (18,6)
cmap_name = "rainbow"
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap_name)
x = df["Population size (millions)"]
y = df["Epedemic intensity, V"]
sz = df["Population size (millions)"].mul(200).astype(int)

# sc = plt.scatter(x, y, c=y, vmin=0, vmax=1, s=sz, cmap=cm, alpha=0.75, edgecolors="dimgrey")
ax = df.plot.scatter(
    "Population size (millions)", "Epedemic intensity, V",
    c=y, vmin=0, vmax=1, s=sz, cmap=cm, alpha=0.75, edgecolors="darkgrey",
    figsize=figsize)
plt.xscale("log")
# plt.colorbar(sc)
plt.subplots_adjust()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, очень здорово получилось. но здесь ранжирование похоже на равные интервалы, можно ли на 7 квантилей разделить? (я добавила картинку к вопросу)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_excel(r"D:\download\10лет.xlsx")

cmap_name = "Spectral_r"
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 6))
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap_name)
x = df["Population size (millions)"]
y = df["Epedemic intensity, V"]
sz = df["Population size (millions)"].mul(75).astype(int)

sc = plt.scatter(x, y, c=y, vmin=0, vmax=1, s=sz, cmap=cm, alpha=0.8, edgecolors="w")
plt.colorbar(sc)
plt.subplots_adjust()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]